# CSS : margin cut accent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a title that *match* margins of the background : two line of title of different colors, each the size of the margin, with no space between
  One of the problem is that `line-height` is ignoring the height of special char (an accent here) and so there is space between the line even with line-height matching their height. I use jQuery to make it adaptative

Here is some code :

```
var marg = 0.09;
var size = 0;

function textsize() {
  size = $(window).height() * marg;
  $("#title").css({fontSize: size});
  $("#title").css('line-height', size+"px")
}
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  textsize();
});
$(document).ready(textsize());
```

I also used `line-height = 100%;`, not better

Thank you !

---

EDIT :
An exemple on JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/enuoLcut/

Comment: Can you share the HTML you're working with?

Comment: Can you show the HTML please? A JSFiddle would be nice too...

Comment: Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/enuoLcut/ ?